# Returning an object with a pointer member variable in C++

Tags: c++

So I have an upDate object that has a pointer member variable that just points to an array that defaults to May 11, 1959:

```
upDate::upDate()
{   dptr = new int[3];
    dptr[0] = 5;
    dptr[1] = 11;
    dptr[2] = 1959;
}
```

Now in my main I'm supposed to override the + operator.

```
upDate D1(5,9,1994);
upDate D2 = D1+1;//supposed to add 1 more day to the upDate.
```

But when I output D2, it doesn't have me 5/10/1994. It gives me a really large negative number: -572662307/-572662307/-572662307.

Here's my operator+ method:

```
upDate upDate::operator+(int integer){
    upDate temp;
    int m = dptr[0];
    //cout << m << endl;
    int d = dptr[1];
    int y = dptr[2];
    int julian = convertToJulian(y, m, d);
    julian += integer;
    //cout << julian << endl;
    temp.convertToGregorian(julian);
    //cout << temp.getMonth() << " " << temp.getDay() << " " << temp.getYear() << endl;
    return temp;
}
```

All the couts in that method were just me testing to see if it's correct, and they are. So, I don't think any of these are incorrect. However, when I return the temp, I think something gets lost along the way of returning the temp as the D2. Maybe it's a pointer issue? I'm not really sure.

Edit: here's my operator=:

```
upDate upDate::operator=(upDate copy) {
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    copy.dptr[i] = dptr[i];
return copy;
}
```

and my destructor:

```
upDate::~upDate()
{
    delete []dptr;
}
```

I guess I never made a copy constructor...But I'm confused on how to make it?

Comment: You have read about [the rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)?

Comment: Have you overloaded the operator =? And show your copy constructor.

Comment: Pileborg and jfly's comments are important, don't ignore them. You can be using assignment and copy constructor without realising (e.g. you're returning a copy of your *temp* object). And in your case, where you have an old-style array of int, you could have a few surprises. Possibly your problem is due to the absence of one of these member functions.

Comment: I posted my operator= and destructor. But I don't think I've made my copy constructor. I'm confused on how I would actually make it...

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe it's a pointer issue?

Probably. In your update, you say "I guess I never made a copy constructor", which means that the class breaks the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722) and has invalid copy semantics. When it's copied (as it is when returning from the function you posted), both copies contain a pointer to the same array; presumably, both have a destructor which deletes the array, leaving the other object's pointer dangling.

> I guess I never made a copy constructor...But I'm confused on how to make it?

The best way to make it is not to. Stop using `new` and manually juggling pointers, and build your class from correctly copyable objects; in this case, replace `dptr` with an array, or three named variables. (If you needed a dynamically-sized array, which you don't here, then `std::vector` would be ideal).

I would probably simplify it further by only storing the Julian day, and only converting to Gregorian when necessary for human-readable presentation.

If you really feel the need to manage memory by steam, then you'll need a destructor

```
~upDate() {delete [] dptr;}
```

a copy constructor

```
upDate(upDate const & other) : dptr(new int[3]) {
    std::copy(other.dptr, other.dptr+3, dptr);
}
```

and a copy-assignment operator. It should modify the object it's called on, not its argument (and certainly not a local copy of its argument, as yours does), and should conventionally return a reference to the assigned object, not a copy of it.

```
upDate & operator=(upDate const & other) {
    std::copy(other.dptr, other.dptr+3, dptr);
    return *this;
}
```

In C++11, you might also want to consider move semantics for the sake of efficiency.

```
upDate(upDate && other) : dptr(other.dptr) {
    other.dptr = nullptr;
}

upDate & operator=(upDate && other) {
    if (this != &other) {   // Careful: self-assignment can be tricky
        dptr = other.dptr;
        other.dptr = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: this code was written without the help of a compiler and test framework, so might contain mistakes. Don't use it without testing.

**tl;dr** Memory management is hard. Don't do it unless you really need to. You don't need to here.

Comment: Well, part of the assignment was to use a pointer data member that points to an integer array. Before, this used 3 integer data members (month, day, year), but I had to change it. But thanks. Putting in the copy constructor made it work now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator=` function works backwards.

```
//This version tries to make a=b work as though it were b=a
upDate upDate::operator=(upDate copy) {
  for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    copy.dptr[i] = dptr[i];
  return copy;
}
```

That is, judging by the [examples I have seen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_in_C%2B%2B) the `operator=` should copy the values of the parameter into the current object, where you have it copying from the current object to the parameter.

```
//Corrected version (judging by linked article.)
upDate & upDate::operator=(upDate copy) {
  for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    dptr[i] = copy.dptr[i];
  return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I never made a copy constructor

**NO**. Note this line `upDate D2 = D1+1;`, it would call copy constructor instead of operator =, since you don't specify one, it would call the compiler-generated copy constructor which performs a member-wise copy, so the data member `D2.dptr = temp.dptr`, they share the same address. After `temp` is destroyed, the `D2.dptr` points to an invalid address, so it gives you garbage value.